# Стилизация выпадающего меню datalist

Tags: html, css, hover, css-selectors, datalist

Каким селектором можно обратиться к выпадающему меню тега `<datalist>`? `datalist > option:hover` или `input[list] > option:hover` не работают.

```html
<p><input list="character">
  <datalist id="character">
    <option value="Чебурашка"></option>
    <option value="Крокодил Гена"></option>
    <option value="Шапокляк"></option>
   </datalist></p>
```

Comment: путь дорога твоя лежит в кастомный character, т.е. не возможно стилизовать, как и select. Просто делай велосипед(

Answer (score 0):

Если обращение к данному элементу необходимо для изменения его стиля, то сделать этого не получится. 
Т.к. для данного элемента браузер сам определяет стили. Поправьте если не прав. Можете изменять `<input>` чтобы выбранное значение изменяла шрифт и так далее.
Если необходимо отловить значение через js, то можно сделать как-то так.

```js
$("#character option").val(); // Получим первое значение option
```